How to send/receive emails with custom domain?
So I've bought a domain name from hostinger and host my website on my personal machine.  I was wondering if it's at all possible to setup an email server on my machine without purchasing an email plan through my domain provider.  I would want to send/receive emails from some email @mydomain.com.  I've looked into smtp-server and nodemailer, but I've only seen steps on how to send/receive emails from other providers such as gmail/yahoo.  I'm not sure the steps specifically and if I need to purchase some sort of service from my domain provider.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is some sample code I attempted with smtp-server, but I believe I am missing some crucial steps (I've tried both ports 25 and 465, as I've heard your ISP can sometimes outright block 25 due to security concerns and neither worked).
import { SMTPServer} from 'smtp-server';
const server = new SMTPServer( {
    onData( stream, session, callback ) {
        console.log( 'email received' );
    }
} );
server.listen( 25 );


Have you configured the DNS records to point to your SMTP server for incoming email? As for sending, unless you enjoy having emails randomly (or always) going to spam, even silently dropped, just use 3rd party service.

Not quite sure how to do that, do you have any resources that may help or can point me in the right direction?

BTW checking port 25/465 both show that they're closed when I run the server.

For receiving you need MX records, for sending technically you don't need any records but any reputable server will drop your email unless you have SPF, DKIM, and DMARC configured correctly, but even that assumes they didn't flag your IP as spammy. If the ports are closed then you haven't set up your port forwarding and/or firewall correctly.

I've opened the ports via my router and configured my firewall by setting new inbound rules for both TCP/UDP for both of the ports.

For the MX record, I have the name set as @, priority 5, content is my domain name, and default TTL as well.
